# Azure devops - edit template with variables

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

I would like to set a variable in the Value for the field Iteration Path in my azure devops template editor.

I created a Template for a Bug and I want this template to be generated with
Iteration Path = Actual Sprint

*In green, the value I want to put a variable.*

[image]

Is there a way to put a variable like : @ActualSprint or $ActualSprint ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check `@CurrentIteration` as it is written [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/query-by-date-or-current-iteration?view=azure-devops):

> Items closed during the current sprint (the `@CurrentIteration` macro references the sprint defined for the current team context)

[image]